# Intergration Bee Intergral

Tags: calculus, contest-math

In the Columbia 2022 intergration bee, one of the problems was $$\int _0 ^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\cos^{2022} (x) }{\sin^{2022} (x) + \cos^{2022} (x) } \, dx.$$ I've tried solving it, but have gotten nowhere. Can anyone present me with the solution?

Comment: Simple use $\int_0^a f(x) dx=\int_0^a f(a-x) dx$

Comment: @ZAhmed I think you're thinking of what would help were the upper limit $\pi/2$.

Comment: Oh! yes, you are right